# Удалить элементы из вложенного словаря python

Tags: python, словари, dict

У меня есть вложенный словарь, подскажите **как можно удалить пустые строки из такого словаря?**

```
myDict = {
'foo': {
'a':[12,””,13, “”],'b':[14,””,””,””] },
'bar': 
{'c':[12,””,””,””],'b':[14,11,13,12] },
'moo':
{'a':[12,””,10,””],'d':[14,””,””,””]
}
}
```

Получить необходимо следующее

```
myDict = {
'foo': {
​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ 'a':[12,13],'b':[14] },
'bar': {
        'c':[12],'b':[14,11,13,12] },
'moo': {
        'a':[12,10],'d':[14 ]
} }
```

Comment: Что именно у вас не получилось?

Comment: Я тоже не знаю(я в python на уровне начальной школы), однако посмотрев про словари, про списки и как их фильтровать, смог добиться нужного результата. А что пытались сделать вы, что бы получить нужный результат?

Comment: ваши вложенные словари приведены с ошибкой. отсутствуют запятые. еще неправильные кавычки и куча непонятных символом вместо табцуляции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через [`filter(function, iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```py
from pprint import pprint

def process(o):
    return dict((k1, dict((k2, list(filter(lambda el: el != '', v2))) for k2, v2 in v1.items())) for k1, v1 in o.items())

my_dict = {
  'foo': {
    'a': [12, "", 13, ""],
    'b': [14, "", "", ""],
  },
  'bar': {
    'c': [12, "", "", ""],
    'b': [14, 11, 13, 12],
  },
  'moo': {
    'a': [12, "", 10, ""],
    'd': [14, "", "", ""],
  },
}

pprint(process(my_dict))
```

Вывод:

```py
{'bar': {'b': [14, 11, 13, 12], 'c': [12]},
 'foo': {'a': [12, 13], 'b': [14]},
 'moo': {'a': [12, 10], 'd': [14]}}
```